# Referencing sheet in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this line of code?

```
Line_Items = Input_File.Input_Sheet.Columns(Column).End(xlDown).Row
```

Input_File is a Workbook, and Input_Sheet is a Worksheet.
I need to specify them becuse neither is Active at this point of running the code

The error message says :

```
Run-time error '438':
Object doesn't support this porperty or method
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such *method* as `Input_Sheet`.  That's what the dot/period does, it qualifies a method/property to an object.

If `Input_Sheet` is already qualified as a worksheet within `Input_File`'s worksheets collection, then just do:

```
Line_Items = Input_Sheet.Columns(column).End(xlDown).Row
```

If it is not, then you need to qualify it:

```
Set InputSheet = Input_File.Worksheets("_sheet_name_")  'Modify as needed
Line_Items = Input_Sheet.Columns(column).End(xlDown).Row
```